# How to add a mask div to cortona3d viewer in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`cortona3d` viewer is a 3D product from www.cortona3d.com, I want to show a mask div before cortona3d viewer, The `aaa` div will not show on front end in my code below

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:500px;height:300px">
    <div class="bbb" style="position: absolute;width:100%;height:100%;transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0); ">
      <embed  src="Aeronaval_assemble.wrl" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-cortona" pluginspage="http://www.cortona3d.com/cortona" vrml_splashscreen="false" vrml_dashboard="false" vrml_background_color="#CDCDCD" contextmenu="false" >      
    </div>
    <div class="aaa" style="position: absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background:blue;transform:translate3d(0, 0, 100px); "></div>
</div>
```